# json data not showing

Tags: php, android

i'm trying to connect mysql database server xampp to android studio,i wrote php code and when i run the code ,the result not showing anything.
here is my code:

### connection.php

```
<? php
define ('hostname','localhost');
define ('user','root');
define ('password','1993');
define ('dbname','mat');

$connect = mysqli_connect(hostname,user,password,dbname);

$mysqli->query("set character_set_server='utf8'");
$mysqli->query("set NAMES 'utf8'");
?>
```

php to fetch data from database:

### show.php

```
<?php
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"){
include 'connection.php';
ShowMat();
}

function ShowMat()
{
global $connect;

$query = "Select * from mat;";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
$number_of_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

$temp_array = array();

if($number_of_rows > 0) {

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
$temp_array[] = $row;
}


}
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array("mata"=>$temp_array));

mysqli_close($connect);
}
```

[image: json result]

How can I solve this?

Comment: how do you "run the code"? Sure it's `POST`?

Comment: you should always check for errors (on establishing connection, on mysqli_query, etc)

Comment: and you're mixing procedual style with oop style. This might work here, but can get really confusing...

Comment: ah, just saw the image at the end. This is clearly not `POST`, it's a `GET` request. So `if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST")` will fail.

Comment: google for "REST Client" to find an addon for chrome/firefox/whatever to be able to send a custom `POST` request.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `REQUEST_METHOD` is `GET` so your code :

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"){
```

so this condition will fail that is why you are not getting any echo.

You can use [POSTMAN](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en) to test your apis give it a try its really useful.

Answer (score 0):

You change this line mysqli_fetch_assoc to this line while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))

Answer (score 0):

This line is creating problem :if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST").Check what type of data are you sending.Are you sending raw data or structured data.Try isset($_REQUEST['']). Example :

```
$action=isset($_REQUEST['action'])?$_REQUEST['action']:"";

switch($action)
{
 case "ShowMat":
       ShowMat();
}

function ShowMat()
{
// code
}
```